# Chef Recipes - Setting node attributes in ruby_block

Tags: ruby, scope, dsl, chef-infra

I have a Chef recipe for a multi-node web service, each node of which needs to get the hostname and IP of the other nodes, to put it into its own local configuration.

The code is shown below. The problem is that when the node.set[][] assignments are made in the ruby_block as shown, the values are empty when the template that relies upon them is created. If I want to create that template, I have to move all of the ruby_block code outside, and have it "loose" in the recipe. Which makes it harder to do unit-testing with Chefspec and the like.

Can any Chef guru set me straight? Is it just impossible to do node.set[] like this inside of a ruby_block? And if so, why doesn't it say so in the [docs?](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_ruby_block.html)

```
$cm = { :name => "web", :hostname => "" , :ip_addr => "" }
$ca = { :name => "data", :hostname => "" , :ip_addr => "" }
$cg = { :name => "gateway", :hostname => "" , :ip_addr => "" }
$component_list = [$cm, $ca, $cg]

ruby_block "get host addresses" do
  block do
    for cmpnt in $component_list
       # do REST calls to external service to get cmpnt.hostname, ip_addr
       # .......
       node.set[cmpnt.name]['name'] = cmpnt.name
       node.set[cmpnt.name]['host'] = cmpnt.hostname
       node.set[cmpnt.name]['ip'] = cmpnt.ip_addr   
    end
  end
end

template "/etc/app/configuration/config.xml" do
  source "config.xml.erb"
  variables( :dataHost => node['data']['host'],
       :webHost =>  node['web']['host'],
       :gatewayHost =>  node['gateway']['host'] )
  action :create
end
```

I also added

```
  subscribes  :create, "ruby_block[get host addresses]", :immediately
```

to the template definition to ensure that the ruby_block ran before the template was created. This didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is an old post, however for future reference, I just ran across [this gist](https://gist.github.com/arangamani/4659646) which gives a nice example of node variable assignments in the Compile vs. Converge phases. To adapt the gist to your example, you'll need to add code like the following to your `ruby_block`:

```
       template_r = run_context.resource_collection.find(:template => "/etc/app/configuration/config.xml")

       template_r.content node['data']['host']
       template_r.content node['web']['host']
       template_r.content node['gateway']['host']
```

For Chef 11, also see [Lazy Attribute Evaluation](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_common.html#lazy-attribute-evaluation).

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that attribute values inside your template resource definition get evaluated before actually invoking any resources.
I.e. the file is first executed as simple Ruby, compiling the resources, and only the the resource actions gets invoked. By that time, it is too late already.
I ran into the same problem when trying to encapsulate certain attribute manipulations into a resource. It simply does not work. Should anyone know a solution to this problem, I would appreciate it very much.

EDIT:

```
b = ruby_block...
...
end
b.run_action(:create)
```

Could possibly do the trick. It invokes the resource immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to this is to not use chef attributes and not use ruby_block to do the work of talking to the REST API.  The code can also be moved to a custom resource for better reuse:

```
unified_mode true
provides :my_resource

action :run do
  cm = { :name => "web", :hostname => "" , :ip_addr => "" }
  ca = { :name => "data", :hostname => "" , :ip_addr => "" }
  cg = { :name => "gateway", :hostname => "" , :ip_addr => "" }
  component_list = [cm, ca, cg]

  hash = {}

  for cmpnt in component_list
     # do REST calls to external service to get cmpnt.hostname, ip_addr
     # .......
     hash[cmpnt.name] = {}
     hash[cmpnt.name]['name'] = cmpnt.name
     hash[cmpnt.name]['host'] = cmpnt.hostname
     hash[cmpnt.name]['ip'] = cmpnt.ip_addr   
  end

  template "/etc/app/configuration/config.xml" do
    source "config.xml.erb"
    variables( :dataHost => hash['data']['host'],
       :webHost =>  hash['web']['host'],
       :gatewayHost =>  hash['gateway']['host'] )
    action :create
  end
end
```

By using unified_mode and moving into a custom resource, it also makes it easier to use a node attribute without requiring the use of lazy {} or ruby_blocks.  It also still allows chef configuration (like setting up resolv.conf or other network requirements before doing the REST calls) prior to calling this code while not having to think about compile/converge two pass issues in recipe context.

There is also no reason to use a resource like ruby_block to do pure ruby processing which does not change the system under management.  In this case the ruby_block is hitting a REST service purely to collect data.  That does not need to be placed into a Chef resource.  It isn't clear from the question if that was being done because the questioner though it was a "best practice" (in this case it is not), or if it was being done to move execution to compile time in order to allow other chef resources that aren't part of the question to fire first (in which case using a custom resource is a much better solution than using a ruby_block).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question, but in case someone is still looking for it, **lazy evaluate** is your friend:

```
template '/tmp/sql_file.sql' do
  source "sql_file.sql.erb"
  mode 0700
  variables lazy {

    # Create a new instance of MySQL library
    mysql_lib = Acx::MySQL.new(
      '127.0.0.1', 'root', node['mysql']['service']['pass']
    )
    password = node['mysql']['service']['support_admin']['ct_password']

    # It returns the encrypted password after evaluate it, to 
    # be used in template variables
    { admin_password:  mysql_lib.encrypted_password(password) }
  }
end
```

https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#lazy-evaluation